# ¿Cómo puedo hacer aparecer un dialogo al pulsar un tag a dentro de la fila de una tabla mysql?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una página que muestra el contenido de una tabla mysql, necesito que cuando den clic en una fila de la tabla muestre un diálogo (popup) con la información completa de la fila de la tabla.
El dialogo me sale bien pero no logro pasar al diálogo el índice de la tabla para buscar la fila que deseo mostrar.
Estoy llamado al diálogo con un tag a en una de las columnas de la tabla

```
<a href='#' name="dialogo" id="dialogo" onclick="overlay()">ReadMore</a>
```

donde La información a mostrar en el diálogo esta dentro de un

```
<div id="overlay">
```

y tengo la función:

```
function overlay() {
  el = document.getElementById("overlay");
  el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

Solo me falta pasar el id de la tabla al diálogo.

#### EDITADO, TOMADO DE LA RESPUESTA AGREGADA POR EL OP

Este es parte del código:

```
while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $fila["id_trainingkit"];
        $tit = $fila["tit"];
        $des = $fila["des"];
        ...
<tr>
<td><? echo $tit; ?> </td>
<td align="center"><? echo $desclan; ?>  </td>
<td>
<? 
$puntero = $id;
echo $ldesc; ?> ...<a href='#' name="b" id="b" onclick="<? $puntero = $id; ?>;overlay()">ReadMore</a> 
<?

. . . 

<!-- The Modal -->

<div id="overlay">
 <div>
<?
   $sel1 = $sel1 . "Where id_trainingkit = ". $puntero_fila;
   $con = mysql_query($sel1, $conn);
   $f = mysql_fetch_array($con);
   $c = $f["id_trainingkit_category"];
   $ti = $f["title"];
   $d = $f["descrip"];
?>
  <table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" width="100%" align="center">
  <tr>
  <td align="right" valign="top" width="6%">Title</td><td align="left" valign="top" width="94%"><? echo $ti; ?></td>
  </tr><tr>        
  <td align="right" valign="top">Category</td><td align="left" valign="top"><? echo $desc; ?></td>
  </tr><tr>
  <td align="right" valign="top">Description</td><td align="left" valign="top"><? echo $d; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="right"><a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>Close</a></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como estas mostrando la tabla? Podrías pasarle el id de la fila a la función overlay

Answer (score 0):

Si la fila de la tabla que contiene el ancla tiene un id o algún identificador específico podrías capturarlo en el evento click:

```
function overlay (event) {
  el = event.target.parentNode
  el.style.visibility = ...
}
```

O con jQuery (ya que le gusta tanto a la gente):

```
el = $(event.target).parent();
```

Saludos y suerte!

Comment: Gracias por responder a mi pregunta. No soy muy ducho en esa materia pero tengo mis dudas:

Comment: ¿Has probado la solución que comento? ¿Te ha funcionado?

Comment: La fila de la tabla si tiene un ancla y esta en una variable ($id). Al capturar el evento click ¿Dónde tengo que poner esa variable? y después de tenerlo en la función overlay ¿cómo la paso para el html para buscar los elementos de la tabla con una select?

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y añadir el código completo de una fila de la tabla? Nos sería de gran ayuda para ver que está pasando.

Comment: Disculpa donde tengo que poner la variable en el tag a y después como pasarlo para el html con php para buscar los elementos de la fila y mostrarlos en el diálogo.

Comment: En la página yo muestro el contenido de la tabla con una select y pongo en variables los elementos de cada fila, Dentro del ciclo que muestra las filas de la tabla en html, tengo el tag a

Comment: Por lo que entiendo tienes un `select`, este a su vez contiene `options` que a su vez contienen los anclas o etiquetas `a`. Tu lo que quieres es modificar el `option` que contiene el `a` sobre el que se hace click?

Comment: El tag <a href='#' name="b" id="b" onclick="<? $puntero = $id; ?>;overlay()">ReadMore</a> esta al final de la última columna de la tabla. Necesito pasar la variable $id que es el identificador de la fila para el diálogo después del <div id="overlay"> de manera que pueda ejecutar otra select para buscar los elementos de la fila que se seleccionó.

Comment: Disculpa el código es extenso y no me deja pasarlo. ¿Podríamos chatear con facebook? porque aqui no me deja.

Comment: Por lo que veo lo estás haciendo con PHP y yo no tengo ni idea. Siento no serte de más ayuda, pero seguro de que algún ninja de ese lenguaje te podrá ayudar mejor que yo.